# Blank after selecting 'install ubuntu'

Tags: 11.04, drivers

Hardware, new mac running some Radeon derivative.  Looked at a few tutorials which ask me to press f6 and set 'nomodeset' but these all seem to be AFTER installing ubuntu.  Where as i can't even get into the installer without the screen going black/blank.

Tried the alternate CD to no avail.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Edit: I have tried thus far

Editing grub with arguments

- nomodeset
- xforcevesa
- Installing with pendrive and cdrom

Hitting f6 at startup provides no changes to the interface as per a [guide i was following](http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2010/05/06/ubuntu-10-04-lucid-blank-screen-at-startup-workaround/)

Comment: You should be able to press F6 *before* choosing the menu option "Install Ubuntu".

Comment: Have tried that, nothing actually happens.  I've tried editing the grub commands with nomodeset and xforcevesa and then loading the install and have had no success.

Comment: I too am faccing same issue with my HP 8000 Elite Small Form Factor (SFF) desktop. I have often observed this issue when the hardware (i.e. computer on which ubuntu is to be installed) is released later than ubuntu release. I think best solution in sight is switch back to ubuntu 10.10 or wait for 11.10. --
Amol

Comment: When you are booting from the CD - you should see a purple screen with a keyboard logo at the bottom.  When you see that hit the Esc or Space-bar - you will then be presented with the install options where you can press F6.

Comment: @fossfreedom I do not get this with natty, i do however get this with Maverik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will watch for any additions, but for the time being the only method i found of doing this was installing 10.04 LTS (maverick).